# Custom waveform/sequence PXI-5412

Tags: labview, waveform

I am very new with LabView, and I am learning to control some instruments.

Can anyone give a clue about how to generate a square waveform using NI PXI-5412 AWG??

A basic signal is easy to generate, but if I want a "custom" signal, I am not able to generate it.

By "custom" I want to mean, for example, a waveform with:

0 + pulse up + 0 + pulse down + 0 + pulse down + 0 + pulse up... and repeat

To be more clear, something like this (poor) draw:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to example VI in your computer: C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2013\examples\instr\niFgen\Fgen Arb Sequence.vi Change Waveform Data input to meet to your requirements or open LabVIEW go to help>find examples>search> and type 5412. There are many examples that could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Khachik, but this example I have been looking at it before, without any luck. I think it is not a very good example. However, at the beginning, I didn't know if I had to go for this example or for the other one called "Fgen Arbitrary Waveform.vi", now, thanks to your answer I think I should go for the arbitrary sequence.....which is not enough, but it is a good first step though. Thanks.